# Inverse Function: If $g(x) = x^2 + 8x$ with $x \geq −4$, find $g^{−1}(33)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $g(x) = x^2 + 8x$ with $x \geq −4$, find $g^{−1}(33)$.

How would I solve this?

Comment: Note that $x^2+8x-33$ factors nicely.

Comment: Hint: $g^{-1}(33)$ is the set of values $A$ such that $g(x) = 33$. Hence, we must solve $x^{2} + 8x = 33$...

Comment: André Nicolas - Why was it your first step to factor it?

Answer (score 2):

Remember, $g^{-1}(33)$ must be a value $x$, such that $x \geq -4$, and $g(x) = 33$. That means, you should find a solution to $$33 = x^2 + 8x$$
Since it's a quadratic equation, it will probably have two solutions. Discard the solution that is less than $-4$ and you are done.

Comment: I thought g^-1(33) is an inverse thus a y value. You however said it is a value of x? Can you explain?

Comment: Think of the structure $g : \mathrm{Dom}(g) \rightarrow \mathrm{Codom}(g)$. If $x$ is an element of $\mathrm{Dom}(g)$, then $g(x)$ belongs to $\mathrm{Codom}(g)$ (to the image of $g$, to be more exact). The question is, if $g^{-1}$ makes any sense, we have $g^{-1}: \mathrm{Im}(g) \rightarrow \mathrm{Dom}(g)$. This way, $g^{-1}(33)$ represents an element of $\mathrm{Dom}(g)$. The question, in simple terms, is: "what value of $\mathrm{Dom}(g)$ gives an image of $33$?"

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$y=g(x) \equiv x^2+8x \equiv(x+4)^2-16 .$$

To find the inverse function, swap $x$ and $y$ to give:
$$x=(y+4)^2-16 \tag{*}.$$

Now, re-arrange $(^*)$ to give $$\boxed{y=g^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{x+16} -4} \tag{**}$$

Then, once you've found $g^{-1}(x)$, simply substitute $x=33$ into $(^{**})$ to find $g^{-1}(33)$.

Comment: You should note that since $g$ is not injective, $g^{-1}$ is not a function. Note that $y = g^{-1}(x) = -\sqrt{x+16} - 4$ is also a solution.

Comment: @ChrisK In the given interval, $[4,\infty)$, $g$ **is** injective (and subsequently $g^{-1}(x)=-\sqrt{x+16}-4$ is **not** a solution).

Comment: If you restrict the domain, yes. However, **why** you choose the positive square root may not be "obvious" to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

$$0=x^2+8x-g(x)$$
By the quadratic equation, we get
$$x=\frac{-8\pm\sqrt{64+4g(x)}}{2}=-4\pm\sqrt{16+g(x)}$$

However, since $x\ge-4$, we conclude $x=-4+\sqrt{16+g(x)}$

Plugging in $g(x)=33$, yields our (conveniently pretty) solution.